# Why is my globalState state object being updated before I update it myself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, use-context

I have a multitabbed view that I am controlling the data with through a global state, being passed through useContext (along with the setState updater function).

The structure is similar to

```
globalState: {
    company: {
        list: [
            [{name: ..., ...}, {field1: ..., ... }],
            [{name: ..., ...}, {field1: ..., ... }],
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

I have a table in this first tab, where each row that displays the details in the first object of each inner list array (`globalState.company.list[X][0]`), and has a few checkboxes to toggle fields in the second object in each inner list array (`globalState.company.list[X][1]`).

The issue I am having is that when I check a checkbox for a specific field, all companies have that field set to that value *before* I call `setGlobalState(...)` in that `onChange` call from the checkbox itself.

Here is all the related code for the flow of creating the checkbox and the handler:

```
<td><Checkbox
    disabled={tpr.disabled} // true or false
    checked={tpr.checked} // true or false
    onChange={checkboxOnChange} // function handler
    targetId={company.id} // number
    field={"field1"} />
</td>
```

Checkbox definition

```
const Checkbox = React.memo(({ disabled, checked, onChange, targetId, field }) => {
    return (
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            style={ /* omitted */ }
            defaultChecked={checked}
            disabled={disabled}
            onChange={(e) => onChange(e, targetId, field)}
        />
    );
});
```

onChange Handler callback

```
const checkboxOnChange = (e, id, field) => {
    const checked = e.target.checked;

    console.log("GLOBAL STATE PRE", globalState.companies.list);

    let foundCompany = globalState.companies.list.find(company => company[0].id === id);
    foundCompany[1][field].checked = checked;
    console.log("foundCompany", foundCompany);

    console.log("GLOBAL STATE POST", globalState.companies.list);

    setGlobalState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        companies: {
            ...prevState.companies,
            list: prevState.companies.list.map(company => {
                console.log("company PRE ANYTHING", company);
                if (company[0].id === foundCompany[0].id) {
                    console.log("Inside here");
                    return foundCompany;
                }
                console.log("company", company);
                return company;
            })
        }
    }));
};
```

I see from the **GLOBAL STATE PRE** log that if I were to check a box for field1, then all companies would have field1 checked well before I modify anything else. I can confirm that before the box is checked, the globalState is as I expect it to be with all of the data and fields correctly set on load.

In the picture below, I checked the box for TPR in the second company array, and before anything else happens, the second and third companies already have the TPR set to true.

[image: Browser console showing the GLOBAL STATE PRE log message]

Any help would be appreciated, and I will share any more details I am able to share. Thank you.

Comment: Because you're mutating it before you log it: `foundCompany[1][field].checked = checked `

Comment: That line happens after I do the global pre log, and in any case, since it was from a find(), it should only be the single, affected company slot, right? I can understand this line affecting the original array, but the order of the updating and logging does not make sense.

Comment: @jonrsharpe When I remove the whole foundCompany bit, and changing the if statement inside of that map to ```if (company[0].id == id) { company[1][field].checked = checked; }```, the same thing occurs, confirming that the line you mentioned did not matter.

Comment: "Do not mutate the state". Do shallow or deep copying before you manipulate the state.

Comment: `if (company[0].id == id) { company[1][field].checked = checked; }` This is still mutating the state.

Comment: I disagree with the shallow copy stuff. While bad, should not be the root cause of having all forms improperly rendered. How do you render your form? I'd suspect you ve missed your 'tpr' initialization

Answer (score 1):

Just don't mutate the state object directly:

```
const checkboxOnChange = (e, id, field) => {
    const checked = e.target.checked;
    setGlobalState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        companies: {
            ...prevState.companies,
            list: prevState.companies.list.map(company => {
                if (company[0].id === id) {
                    return {
                        ...company,
                        checked
                    };
                }
                return {
                    ...company
                };
            })
        }
    }));
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I glossed over this fact in the comments in the question post, but did not think it through. I appreciate your answer here and in the other response.

Answer (score 0):

The globalState object is being updated before you call setGlobalState because you are mutating the current state (e.g. `foundCompany[1][field].checked = checked;`)

One way of getting around this issue is to make a copy of the state object so that it does not refer to the current state. e.g.

```
var cloneDeep = require('lodash.clonedeep');

...

let clonedGlobalState = cloneDeep(globalState);
let foundCompany = clonedGlobalState.companies.list.find(company => company[0].id === id);
foundCompany[1][field].checked = checked;
```

I recommend using a deep clone function like [Lodash's cloneDeep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep) as using the spread operator to create a copy in your instance will create a shallow copy of the objects within your list array.

Once you have cloned the state you can safely update it to your new desired state (i.e. without worry of mutating the existing globalState object) and then refer to it when calling setGlobalState.

Comment: This is not a good solution. OP is already using deep object destructuring to create new instances, and now you're introducing a new library for doing exactly that. Solution is to change the `checked` flag inside the setState callback.

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković The OP is mutating the original state in their call to `foundCompany[1][field].checked = checked;`. They need to create a clone of the data with no references to the original global state object before they do this, as detailed in my answer. Also the "vanilla" javascript spread operator when used to create copies of objects in setGlobalState does a shallow copy not a deep copy when working with objects (which are what in the company array). Hence again for the need to use a deep copy function such as cloneDeep.

Comment: "The OP is mutating the original state in their call to foundCompany[1][field].checked = checked;" I know, that's why I said "solution is to change the checked flag inside the setState callback", not before. "Also the "vanilla" javascript spread operator when used to create copies of objects in setGlobalState does a shallow copy". Except when you destucture inner objects as well, which OP already is doing.